# Preg_replace_all links to markdown format

Tags: php, markdown

We're converting to markdown, before we used an 'in-house' system, where both the image links and all data with it (e.g. alt) in another bracket.

For example `{IMAGE LINK}[OPTIONAL ALT WITH OTHER DATA]`

Now we are moving to markdown, (our data is stored as markdown in the database), I need to convert everything into markdown:

So How can I turn all instances of `{LINK}[OPTIONAL DATA]` (square brackets not required, so some are just {}) into markdown equivalent:

Basically,

`{http://www.youtube.com/image.gif}[this
 is optional alt]` INTO
 `![alt](http://www.youtube.com/Image.gif)`

I have the following so far, but do I deal with the optional [ALT DATA] tag?

```
   if (preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/i', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) 
   {


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with the optional alt attribute you should use preg_replace_callback. This allows you to test for the existence of the alt attr and add it if necessary.

```
$str = '
This is an image {http://www.youtube.com/image.gif}[this is optional alt]
This is an image with an alt attribute {http://www.youtube.com/image.gif}
';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~{(http://[^s]+)}(?:\[(.*?)\])?~',
    function($m){
        if ( isset( $m[2] ) ) {
            return $img = sprintf( '![%s](%s)', $m[2], $m[1] );
        }
        return $img = sprintf( '(%s)', $m[1] );
    },
    $str
);
```

Comment: You're missing a ![] from the second return (its required), but other than that, this is correct

Comment: @jonnnie: im not missing a ![], that return statement is for images with alt attribs

Answer (score 0):

The simple case would be

```
{(.*?)}\[(.*?)\]   <-- search pattern
![\1](\2)           <-- replace pattern
```

but you'll be messed up with links that contain the escaped characters (`\{`, `\}`, `\[`, `\]`). It would involve a lookahead that you'll have to hope someone else writes up for you. However, if this is just image URLs, you shouldn't have too many (if any) instances of that happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace_callback` for that purpose. There it's easier to probe for the optional alt tag and/or construct a replacement.

```
 $source = preg_replace_callback('#
        \{  (http://[^}\s]+)  \}  
        (?:                        
          \[ ([^\]{}\n]+) \]        
        )?
     #x',
     "cb_img_markdown",
     $source);

 function cb_img_markdown($m) {
     list($asis, $link, $alt) = $m;
     if (!strlen($alt)) {
         $alt = "image " . basename($link);
     }
     return "![$alt]($link)";
 }
```

You could also make the link match stricter to avoid false positives. Here I just made it depend on `http://` being present, but you could append e.g. `(?:png|jpe?g|gif)` to ensure it only matches image urls.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show what Markdown uses to match ![alt](link)

Comment: You copied the wrong part. The inline image handling is the regex below that one.

Comment: Ok, I've removed it...no wonder I was getting this wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is so hectic in to parse tags in PHP,
I would suggest you should use this  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

it is very easy to parsing any kind tags, and you can easily filter by attributes also.